# In the Selenium IDE, how would you save stored values to a file?

Tags: variables, selenium, file-io, selenium-ide

I'm using the Selenium IDE to capture values from a web site, and I'm saving those values into variables.

Now I'm looking for a way to print / output those variables to a file and I'm not finding much information about the process in the help documents.

Is this possible to do this without an additional intermediary or scripting language?

Comment: Why not use selenium webdriver?

Comment: Post what you've tried. First thought, open a file and write to it.

Comment: @bcar - can this be done without a scripting language on the PC? This is getting rolled out to windows users who won't have python / php / etc. installed.

Comment: So you're having your users use the IDE to record there tests and you want that data written to text file, right?

Comment: @bcar essentially, yes.

Comment: I dont believe that is possible, but after its recorded you could output to some language like java, then implement file io so  that each time it runs you get the local file and the data. Seems like a lot of work. Dont understand the value.

Comment: I doubt the users will have Java on their systems either.  We're integrating Selenium into an existing software suite and rolling it out to users.  We can tell them to install Selenium, obviously. But asking them to install Selenium + a language on their desktop is a bit much.